# Programatically add RibbonPage/Group/Item to a RibbonControl which is already merged

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, plugins, devexpress

I'm working on a **plugin-framework** which shall accept **plugins** which implement my public interface and which have a GUI done with **DevExpress.RibbonControl**. I have no problems loading the plugins and merging the **RibbonControl** of the **plugin-framework** with the **RibbonControl** of the **plugin**. When I create a **RibbonPage**, **RibbonPagrGroup** or an **Item** in a **PageGroup** and add this programatically to my **plugin** **RibbonControl** nothing appears on screen but when I debug I can see that the elements have been added to my **plugin RibbonControl**. It seems DevExpress does not redraw whatever is added after the merge between the **plugin RibbonControl** and the **framework RibbonControl**. Problem now is that my **framework** does not know when it needs to **UnmergeRibbon()** and **MergeRibbon()** again so my question is: Is there any way from my plugin code to force the **MergedRibbons** to **"ReMerge()"** ?

I'm working with DevExpress version 14.2.11 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The merging is the one-time operation, so it is necessary to add all the items before two RibbonControls will be merged. After the operation is completed, the only way to update the parent RibbonControl if items were dynamically added to the child one is to manually un-merge RibbonControls and merge them again.

There are public methods to [merge](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonControl_MergeRibbontopic)/[unmerge](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraBarsRibbonRibbonControl_UnMergeRibbontopic) RibbonControls, but this is not the right way to go. The correct way is to add all items to the child RibbonControl before displaying its container.

This may be not that easy, when it comes to developing a plugin-framework rather than a simple WinForms applications. If there is no way to add items at the proper moment, it is probably easier to develop a simple custom merge/unmerge functions that will add/remove items according to your own rules.

Comment: I know about the standard merge/unmerge methods, as you pointed out it is problematic to know all child controls at the time the plugin RibbonControl is merged with the framework PluginControl. At the moment I'm stuck with having only static plugins, there seems to be no way working around that other than implementing a way of communicating between plugin and framework in the interface. Thanks for you feedback anyways.